# How to set Websocket to communicate with a client and a server-sent-events server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket

I need to build a 2 way communication between a browser and an REST API service.

One of the most complex thing I am facing is checking the API for updates every second.

I have two types of communication

1. Browser passes data and a command to the API. The API executes the command and returns a respond.
2. Check the API every second, update the user's cache, send the cache content of the cache to the browser.

I tried different techniques to handle this, but none of them worked good and all were not scale-able.

Here are some techniques I tried

1. Call the API every second using `setInterval()` function in Javascript.
2. Server-Sent-Events (SSE)
3. Call the API every second using `setInterval()` function inside a ShardWorker.

I am hoping I can do this communication using a WebSocket and node.js.

How can WebSocket handler both communication types listed above?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to handle this is using socket.io

http://socket.io/docs/ you can find the documentation,

Basically on the client you can do `socket.on('cache', function(msg) { //blabla });

And in the server, when the cache is updated socket.emit('cache', msg);

Comment: I came across socket.io but note sure how the technique is going to work. Do I need to have a nodejs server setup to handle the API requests and also and websocket to be as a middle man? How do I ping the API every second to get new data?

Comment: API and socket.io server can coexist in the same server.
Basically, the client will not ask every second for the data, but will be the server to just send the data when it is available. of course, you have to know when the data gets updated, so that the server can send it to the client

Comment: I am still confused. How will the The Node server know that the API have new data without pinging it every second? The API is an external service that I have to check every second to see if there is new event.

Comment: Is the API yours? if yes, you have access to the data, and know exactely when you have new data in the cache, so you can send it. If the API is not yours, then the only solution is to keep asking every minute from the client

Comment: The API is not mine. So I will have to ping it every second. But how will I set the Websocket to ping the server every second, update a cache "array" and then send the data to the client. I don't want to open a new connection to the API every time a browser is refreshed or a new tab opens

Comment: You have to see if the API supports websocketa, if it does not have it you have to use the good old ajax for that. With an interval

Comment: I am still not clear on how/where would I start the setinterval calls. On what event i can start the setinterval call without causing multiple request started from one user